# Refire certain scripts after jQuery AJAX load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I need certain scripts to refire after an AJAX load. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [success](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) callback to invoke the functions you want to refire.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/url',
    success: function() {
        func1();
        func2();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is great. I'm using the `$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "test.js", dataType: "script" });` from the jQuery website to get the scripts, but would it be possible to create a database of sorts and have it refire certain scripts when loading certain pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to reattach events try the [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback function

> A callback is a plain JavaScript
>   function passed to some method as an
>   argument or option. Some callbacks are
>   just events, called to give the user a
>   chance to react when a certain state
>   is triggered. jQuery's event system
>   uses such callbacks everywhere:

More info [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Options)